# Angular 5, Parent input variable doesn't interact with child component as expected

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-components

I have 4 items:

A view container, edit container, view-edit component, text-field input component.

View Container:

```
<app-view-edit
    viewMode="true">
</app-view-edit>
```

Edit Container:

```
<app-view-edit
    viewMode="false">
</app-view-edit>
```

the view-edit component uses the input variable

```
@Input() public viewMode: boolean
```

and passes it to my text-field input component inside the view-edit component

```
<text-field
   label="xxxx"
   name="xxxx"
   placeholder=""
   [readonly]="viewMode"
   [(ngModel)]="xxx.xxx">
</text-field>
```

The text-field component is set up as such:

text-field.html:

```
<div>
    <label *ngIf="label" [attr.for]="identifier">{{label}}</label>
    <input   
        type="text"
        [readonly]="readonly"
        [placeholder]="placeholder"
        [(ngModel)]="value"
        [ngClass]="{invalid: (invalid | async )}"
        class="form-control"     
        [id]="identifier"
    />
    <app-validation-messages  
        *ngIf="invalid | async"
        [messages]="failures | async">
    </app-validation-messages>
</div>
```

text-field.ts:

```
import { Component, Optional, Inject, Input, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModel, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, NG_VALIDATORS, NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS } from '@angular/forms';
import { ElementBase } from '../form-base';

@Component({
    selector: 'text-field',
    templateUrl: './text-field.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./text-field.component.css'],
    providers: [{
        provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
        useExisting: TextFieldComponent,
        multi: true,
    }]
})
export class TextFieldComponent extends ElementBase<string> {
    @Input() public label: string;
    @Input() public placeholder: string;
    @Input() public readonly: boolean;

    @ViewChild(NgModel) model: NgModel;

    public identifier = `text-field-${identifier++}`;

    constructor(
        @Optional() @Inject(NG_VALIDATORS) validators: Array<any>,
        @Optional() @Inject(NG_ASYNC_VALIDATORS) asyncValidators: Array<any>,
     ){
        super(validators, asyncValidators);
    }
    getValue(bool: boolean) {
        return false;
    }
}

let identifier = 0;
```

The issue is when the input fields load with the code above, all inputs have the readonly attribute, regardless if I set viewMode as false as displayed in the edit container. I've checked many console logs and functions to determine if the value is being passed as false.

If I turn the text-field.ts line

```
[readonly]="readonly"
```

to

```
[attr.readonly]="readonly"
```

I see < ...  readonly="false" > in the dom.

So I know the values are correct while being passed down..

If I hardcode the readonly property on the text-filed component to either boolean the field renders how I'd expect.

Why am I seeing different behavior by passing the boolean down to the text-filed input through an input variable?

Comment: I ended up changing readonly to disabled and it's working as expected. Why would this be an issue with readonly?

Comment: Why is viewMode in `<app-view-edit
    viewMode="true">
</app-view-edit>` without brackets? If you don't put brackets, it won't bind it to the property, thus viewMode will be undefined in the `@Input` of the child

Comment: You need brackets if you're binding a model variable. `viewMode="true"` will pass down `true`, if I wanted to pass say a set variable from the component, such as a vairable `isViewMode`, then I'd use `[viewMode]="isViewMode"`or `viewMode="{{isViewMode}}` and then i'd be passing that variable's value.

Comment: I can't edit my comment so I'm tagging you in this one :) @K.Gkinis

Comment: `viewMode="false"` passes the **string** 'false', which is truthy. If you want "false" to be interpreted as an Angular expression, and thus as the boolean `false`, you need `[viewMode]="false"`.

Comment: @JBNizet what you suggested works. I ended up switching readonly to disabled and that worked with my set up. It's strange that this setup breaks readonly but works for disabled. perhaps it's a way disabled takes the string false. Thank you.